# Import Dump: Cannot Locate Master Table

Tags: oracle, import, datapump

I'm trying to import a dump file with the command below:

```
impdp system/password dumpfile=mw0sd1.dmp keep_master=Y
```

But it returns following error:

```
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39059: dump file set is incomplete
ORA-39246: cannot locate master table within provided dump files
```

I've been checked logfile and didn't found any error for master table.

```
Export: Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on Fri Mar 2 01:31:27 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
;;; 
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
Starting "SYS"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_02":  userid="/******** AS SYSDBA" directory=BKPSQL1 dumpfile=BKP_MW0SD1_PONTUAL_2392329.dmp LOGFILE=BKP_MW0SD1_PONTUAL_2392329.log SCHEMAS=MW0SD1
```

Master Table:

```
Master table "SYS"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_02" successfully loaded/unloaded
    ******************************************************************************
    Dump file set for SYS.SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_02 is:
      /home/oracle/orabkp/BKPORA/ORAINST1/SQL1/BKP_MW0SD1_PONTUAL_2392329.dmp
    Job "SYS"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_02" successfully completed at 03:46:24
```

I'll appreciate so much If anyone could help me to solve this question ASAP. Already exported this database 2 times for make sure that is not an export problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What was the `expdp` command that was used?

Comment: Run `impdp` with `trace=1ff0300` and post the trace file that was created. So far all I can tell is your dumpfile is corrupted.